# How to create a wide database selecting one variable from multiple long databases?

Tags: r, pivot

I am trying to create a final database that gathers one specific variable listed in multiple long databases. Each long database refers to a different year - 2021 in this picture below. What I am trying to do is to select only the variable transport(Column 3 - Type) of each Name (column 1) for all the years that I have. But again each long database refers to one specific year. I try to use pivot_wide, but didn't work. Now I even know how to start. Any help is much appreciated.

Database 1 - 2021

| Name | Year | Type | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2021 | Transport | 34531 |
| A | 2021 | Building | 13513 |
| A | 2021 | Park | 65 |
| B | 2021 | Transport | 13454 |
| B | 2021 | Building | 17655 |
| B | 2021 | Park | 75 |
| C | 2021 | Transport | 2345 |
| C | 2021 | Building | 6357 |
| C | 2021 | Park | 56 |

Database 2 - 2020

| Name | Year | Type | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2020 | Transport | 24531 |
| A | 2020 | Building | 3545 |
| A | 2020 | Park | 65 |
| B | 2020 | Transport | 9454 |
| B | 2020 | Building | 15654 |
| B | 2020 | Park | 75 |
| C | 2020 | Transport | 2342 |
| C | 2020 | Building | 4681 |
| C | 2020 | Park | 45 |

Output Desired
Transport

| Name | 2020 | 2021 | 2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 24531 | 34531 | ... |
| B | 9454 | 13454 | ... |
| C | 2342 | 2345 | ... |

Comment: "I try to use pivot_wide, but didn't work."  Please show that code and explain what did not work.

Comment: Please also include some sample data as code. For instance, if you have a data frame called `df`, you can run `dput(df[1:5, 1:4])` to produce a code recipe for us to exactly reproduce the first 5 rows and 4 columns of the table.

Comment: Try `df[df$Type %in% "Transport", ]`?

Comment: Should the output have a `Value` that is the first row for each `Type`-`Year`, or the total for each `Type`-`Year`, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by first binding all the data frame using `rbind`, then using `dplyr::filter` and `tidy::pivot_wider` to restructure the data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

rbind(df1, df2) %>%
  filter(Type == "Transport") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Year, values_from = Value) %>%
  select(1, sort(names(.[-c(1:2)])))
 
#   Name  `2020` `2021`
#   <chr>  <int>  <int>
# 1 A      24531  34531
# 2 B       9454  13454
# 3 C       2342   2345
```